# Rails streaming and uploading at the same page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a page where users see the uploaded videos. Above the videos, there is an "Update" form with the ability to upload videos to the collection. The form uses realtime uploading (Upload starts as soon as user chooses file). And when the upload progress is 100%. The user hits "Update" button to update video collection.

The problem occurs when the user wants to upload a file when watching a video. The upload does not progress. There are no messages or errors in server development log or client javascript console. It just hangs (the video continues playing though). The upload usually hangs at the start (5%, 20% depending on the video file size).

By the way; i use [refile](https://github.com/refile/refile) gem for managing realtime uploads, storage, file serving, etc. Also it should be known that, i use same rails application server (Thin 1.6.3) to serve files and accept uploads. (Maybe the server gets busy and can not accept uploads? Because if i don't start playing the video, the upload progresses smoothly and completes without a problem.)

Could anyone point me in the right direction? Where to look? Are there any parameters i should set somewhere?

Comment: Additional information: http://www.therailsway.com/2009/2/22/file-downloads-done-right/ (I think this may be my problem, though i am not sure)

Comment: what is your concurrency configuration on your thin server?

Comment: If you mean "config.allow_concurrency = true" then, no it is not enabled in my development environment. And i just learned that there is a "--threaded" argument for thin. I will try and update if any difference happens.

Comment: if you don't have the proper concurrency setup, and i assume you don't, because otherwise you would know about it, you can not stream and upload at the same time. simple as that.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Could you elaborate a little more on the proper concurrency setup? What should i do?

Comment: you need to run a webserver that enables concurrent requests, puma for example, and configure rails to allow concurrency. on top of that you application needs to be in a thread-safe way if you use a multi-threaded server, multi-processed servers like unicorn don't need thread safety or concurrency in rails.

Comment: Thanks, would you mind writing an answer to explain these concepts?

Comment: there are books written about those concepts and i don't think that i can boil it down appropriately. TL;DR if you don't know what i'm talking about, you should probably buy such a book or read about concurrency in rails on the interwebs.